# Why do I always have to divide by 49 to get the right answer for a binary converter + cout ambiguity?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I recently started to learn C++, so sorry if I'm making a dumb mistake... Why do I have to divide by 49 to obtain the correct answer? E.g. if I enter `"1111"` then the answer is 735 instead of 15.

This happens with all numbers, e.g. if I enter `"10"` then the answer is 98 instead of 2. Also why are my `cout`s showing ambiguous values? I'm using Visual Studio 2013. (Note the division by 49 happens on the last line)

```
void binaryToDecimal() {
string number = getNumber();
int sum = 0;
int factor = 1;
for (int i = number.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (number.at(i) != '0' && number.at(i) != '1') {
        cout << "Number is not in binary form" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (number.at(i) == '1') {
        sum += number.at(i) * factor;
    }
    factor *= 2;
}
cout << "\'" << number << "\' in binary is \'" << sum / 49 << "\'" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why did you write the function in this way?

Comment: You will get a lot higher quality of responses if you explain what it is that you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Are you confusing digit `char` values with their numeric equivalents??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, obviously. So why not write an answer?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Just too lazy (did you have a look at the clock right now??)! Your turn ...

Comment: shuttle87 its just a homework project.
@πάνταῥεῖ if i take away the single quotes then it never recognises the fact that 1 and 0's are in the string

Comment: I'm beginning to understand **why** [malbolge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge) makes `%94` that prominent ...

Comment: OK, seriously: Use the [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) class to convert from bit-strings.

Comment: sorry let me rephrase the problem, this code works perfectly! BUT in the last line i have to have sum / 49 in order to obtain the correct answer instead of just directly outputting the sum value. why??

Comment: @user3262003 Don't use _magic numbers_, just using `'1'` instead of `49` makes everything clearer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Characters in `string`s are stored internally not being the same as `int`s. This little code snippet hopefully will help you understand the magic number better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    std::string test("1234");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < test.size(); i++){
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(test.at(i)) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
49
50
51
52
```

In particular note that the value from casting the string "1" to an `int` is 49.

To avoid this magic number approach you would probably want to do one of 2 things:

Use a string to int conversion like `boost::lexical_cast` or a 'stringstream` to first convert your string into an integer representation then deal with that. However this changes the logic as you are now using some different math.

Or if you want to keep the logic mostly the same then the easiest thing is to just not deal as `char`s internally once you are past the input stage:

```
using namespace std;

bool binaryToDecimal() {
    string raw_input("101");//This would be your get_number function
    int sum = 0;
    int factor = 1;
    for (size_t i = raw_input.length()-1; i > 0; i--) { //I think you also had an off by one error here
        if (raw_input.at(i) != '0' && raw_input.at(i) != '1') {
            cout << "Number is not in binary form" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        if (raw_input.at(i) == '1') {
            sum += factor; //Previously you had a completely unnecessary number.at(i) in here
        }
        factor *= 2;
    }
    cout << "\'" << raw_input << "\' in binary is \'" << sum << "\'" << endl; //No more magic number required now!
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks i see what you are trying to say, but is there any way that i can remove the need for dividing by 49? in Java i could have just gone Integer.parseInt() to convert to an int from string, is there anything similar in c++?

Comment: @user3262003, I think the best way to handle it is to approach the problem differently. I can include the code for the way I would do this if you want.

Comment: that would be great :)

Comment: @user3262003, I updated by answer.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in ASCII are assigned into code points 0x30-0x39 (or 48-57). When you multiply something by `'1'` of course it always contains the term `'1'` in the result which is 49. You need to convert `'0'` and `'1'` into integer values by subtracting `'0'` from the character

Also, no need to multiply, just read the string from left to right and shift, it'll be much faster